# Variable name for a 2-valued variable passed as boolean?

Tags: c#, .net, variables, boolean

What do you name a variable that is a boolean but can have 2 meaningful values out of N?

Example:  x can have values "red" or "blue".

Calling it bRed, or isRed, is meaningful if he value is true , but doesn't convey any info about the "false" case.

YOu *could* implement it as an int, or if you are picky, as an enum. But this means more lines of code to declare the enum, etc.

I thought of "redOrBlue", but logically speaking, the value is always true :)

What do you think of "redNotBlue"? Any better ideas?

Comment: I tried using an enum, but it adds a lot more code. The situation was 1 of 2 radio buttons. Normally I would just pass the value of radiobutton1.Checked as a parameter. Using an enum means I have to loop through the controls of the groupbox, find the checked radio button, map that to an enumerated value, then handle the enum on the function side with a switch statement.

Comment: Couldn't you just say `radiobutton1.Checked ? ColorEnum.Red : ColorEnum.Blue`? And on the other end, `if(color == ColorEnum.Red)`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should probably be using an enum in this case.

```
enum EntityColors
{
  blue,
  red
};
```

Comment: Beat me to it ;-)
I agree, I think in this particular case, an enum is appropriate, since there is no meaning conveyed by 'true' or 'false.'

Comment: I already considered that, but it means more lines of code for something that isn't any more typesafe or clear. I'll reconsider though.

Comment: @Larry, also think about it later you decide you want to add another color. Is your variable going to be named `RedNotBlueNotYellow`? Or if IsRed is false, does that mean it's blue or yellow? Using enums it's very easy to maintain as well as read.

Comment: See my comment above. I think this is a case where it's not worth it to build in extendability for a case that may never happen.

Answer (score 3):

Just use an `enum` in this case, it's the most expressive:

```
public enum ColorValue { Red, Blue };
```

Comment: already considered that, but it means more lines of code for something that isn't any more typesafe or clear. I'll reconsider though.

Comment: @Larry: It's certainly more *readable* though - you will know exactly what you're dealing with looking at the code, the same can't be said for a boolean. Also, you can much easier extend the value set.

Comment: I think an enum is really more clear. What would you make of some code you inherited where there's a boolean variable declared somewhere with the "most expressive" name 'falseMeansATrueMeansB'?

Answer (score 2):

More lines of code didn't hurt a developer yet. A poorly typed and named variable did. Go and use an enumeration type and use boolean only where it makes sense — i.e. yes/no, true/false logic.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to solve an other problem.

For example you have a print function

```
void print(string text, bool red) {...}
```

Red are important entrys all others are blue. Why not changing the variable name to something more meaningful

```
void print(string text, bool isImportant) {...}
```

This would make the API more clear and as soon you change your important color to say orange you don't have to change your variable name.

Answer (score 0):

This should certainly be defined as an enum.

Your question is "What do you name a variable that is a boolean but can have 2 meaningful values out of N? Example: x can have values "red" or "blue".

A boolean can have two values, "true" or "false". In your example the two possible vales are "red" or "blue", so this dosn't look like a good candidate for a boolean variable.

Implementing as an enum is more lines of code, but is likely to be more extensible and more maintainable in that it's intention will be clear to future developers consuming your code, and so worth the (minor) implementation cost.